# Xcode 8's simulator won't work

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8

I have a problem with the simulator, it doesn't want to start, it blocks to the load screen.

[image]

Comment: If this is solved, please click the tick mark adjacent to the answer below that helped you solve it. If you solved it yourself, please add a new answer and click the tick for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this issue and what solved it was to open the simulator and then in the top menu: **Simulator > Reset content and setting**.

Answer (score 0):

This bar indicates progress through data migration when booting your device.

Restoring your device to default state (Reset Content and Settings) may alleviate the problem, but it would be best if you could capture this state and file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com.  Include ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator, ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/[UDID of stuck device], and `sudo sysdiagnose -q`.  To find the UDID, run `xcrun simctl list` and look for the booted device.